# Is the this a feature or a bug? Windows 10 python time.sleep() hangs when clock rolls over though midnight

Tags: python, windows

python 3.6.7

I have a selenium **scraper** script with a while loop that tests for page content to be updated. There is an initial 5 sec sleep and then 1 sec if the page was unchanged. I frequently find this script stops running and the last data output to file was just before midnight. I have to terminate the script by pressing ctrl-C, it's always one of the `time.sleep()` that appears in the traceback. There are 12 items listed on each page and then next page is loaded by script clicking the "next" button. If there are less than 12 items or no "next" button it has reached the end of the listing and starts over.

```
import time

many lines of page load and site login code

n = 0 #page counter
nx = True
bait_ids = ['dummy']
old_ids = ['dummy']

tg = True
while tg:
    while nx:
        n = n + 1
        time.sleep(5)
        # Selenium hands the page source to Beautiful Soup
        while (list_ids == old_ids):
            time.sleep(1)
            soup_page = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
            list_ids = soup_page.find_all("div", {"class": "dec"})
            
        old_ids = list_ids
        print(len(list_ids)," ", end="")
        ....
        scrape 10 data attributes for each list_ids
        append list_ids and data to text file
        ....
        if (len(list_ids) != 12):
            nx = False
    
        if nx:
            try:
                next_btn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.next')
                next_btn.click()
            except NoSuchElementException:
                if nx:
                    nx = False
```

Example traceback from ctrl-C, it got 12 list_ids and then got stuck for over 8 hours on the `time.sleep(1)`.

```
12  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lf7.py", line 265, in <module
    time.sleep(1)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: If `next_btn.click()` doesn't sufficiently refresh the page, you'll be in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3):

Consider that this bug is not caused by the `time` module. You are already using a `time.sleep(5)` above and your code does not stall in it.

However, the line which seems to be the problem is inside a `while` statement:

```
while (list_ids == old_ids):
    time.sleep(1)
    soup_page = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    list_ids = soup_page.find_all("div", {"class": "dec"})
```

If this loop's conditions are always met, it would be common that stopping it will make it seem like the sleep is the issue, while it's more likely that something went wrong in the execution of the conditions that would exit the loop.

It's possible that something else went wrong while scraping the website, making it stall. There is not enough information about the website being scraped, but if you are scraping a third party's website, they could blocking you from scraping them, since all this code is inside multiple while loops and the constant selenium requests might look like spam.

Comment: Any loop with a `sleep` in it will look like it's hung in the `sleep` even if it isn't, because that's where the code spends 99.9% of its time.

Comment: P.S. Maybe the site being scraped has a once-a-day task to determine who to block, and the task runs at midnight.